# ¿Cómo añadir un valor y mostrarlo?

Tags: javascript

Teniendo lo siguiente:

```js
function C(){
      
      this.id = null;
      
      
    }
    
    var casas = [1,2,3,2];
    
    for (var i=0;i<casas.length;i++) {
      
      var b = new C({
        
        id: i
        
      });
      
      console.log(b.id[i]);
      
    }
```

Lo que quiero lograr es por cada iteración del for cambiar el valor del '`this.id`' del objeto por i y así crear 3 instancias con 3 '`this.id`' diferentes, pero no me funciona, ¿por qué?

Comment: No está claro. por qué iteras `casas`  si luego asignas `i`?  no quieres asignar `casas[i]`? Además te falla al final en el `b.id[i]` porque si quieres acceder al `id` solo has de poner `b.id`

Comment: imaginalo como una cantidad de casas y cada casa tendra su id y c() es el constructor de casa, entonces por cada casa se crea un C() con su propia id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No funciona porque en ninguna momento le dices que la instancia de C debe tener la propiedad id asignada al parametro que le mandas, ahora, la situacion que expones es una de las formas de crear clases en javascript, con la instruccion `new` se crea una instancia de `C`, por dentro puedes tener todo el codigo que necesites, asignar id, obtener id, etc, te dejo un ejemplo mas completo:

```js
function C(){
  //Declaracion de id
  this.id=null;
  //Obtener id
  this.getId = function (){
   return this.id;
  }
  //Asignar id
  this.setId = function (id){
   this.id=id;
  }

}

var casas = [1,2,3,2];

for (var i=0;i<casas.length;i++) {
  console.log("Para la casa en la pos:",i);
  var b = new C();
  b.id=i;//asignacion de id directa
  console.log("Obtener id por metodo de instancia:",b.getId());
  b.setId(i+1);//asignacion de id por metodo de instancia
  console.log("Obtener id por metodo de instancia:",b.getId());
  b.setId(i+2);//asignacion de id por metodo de instancia
  console.log("Obtener id de forma directa :",b.id);
  console.log("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En cada iteración de `casas` creas un nuevo objeto `C` y tras crearlo le asignas el `id` correspondiente.

Si quieres hacerlo en un paso, el constructor tendría que ser

```
function C(id){

    this.id = id;

}
```

Para luego hacer

```
var b = new C(i);
```

Y para mostrar la información de la variable `b` has de poner `b.id` ya que es un valor único, no un array, por eso te falla en `b.id[0]`.

```js
function C(id) {

  this.id = id;


}

var casas = [1, 2, 3, 2];

for (var i = 0; i < casas.length; i++) {

  var b = new C(i);

  console.log("Objeto para la casa " + casas[i] + " tiene una id: " + b.id);

}
```